# Is performing indirection from a pointer acquired from converting an integer value definitely UB?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider this example

```cpp
int main(){
  std::intptr_­t value = /* a special integer value */; 
  int* ptr = reinterpret_­cast<int*>(value ); // #1
  int v = *ptr;  // #2
}
```

[expr.reinterpret.cast] p5 says

> A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a pointer. A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and back to the same pointer type will have its original value; **mappings between pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-defined**.

At least, step `#1` is implementation-defined. For step `#2`, in my opinion, I think it has four possibilities, which are

> 1. The implementation does not support such a conversion, and implementation does anything for it.
> 2. The pointer value is exactly the address of an object of type `int`, the result is well-formed.
> 3. The pointer value is the address of an object other than the `int` type, the result is UB.
> 4. The pointer value is an invalid pointer value, the indirection is UB.

It means what the behavior of the indirection through the pointer `ptr` will be depends on the implementation. It is not definitely UB if the implementation takes option `2`. So, I wonder whether this case is not definitely UB or is definitely UB? If it is latter, which provisions strongly state the behavior?

Comment: I think the key question is - does `*ptr` dereference to an `int` [object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) that was created during the life time of the program?  If it does not then we have UB.

Comment: From a standard perspective, yes, it is undefined behaviour.  It is possible to map a pointer to an integral value and then map that integral value pack to a pointer - but the mapping (in either direction) is implementation-defined.  Among other things, this may mean that a round-trip mapping (e.g. pointer to integral value to pointer) may not give the original value.  More generally, it is implementation-defined whether mapping from an integral value to a pointer gives a valid pointer to an object.  If the pointer does not point at a valid object, dereferencing it gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter From the standard perspective, I don't think it is definitely UB. Moreover, a round-trip mapping is definitely well-formed since the standard guarantees that.

Comment: @xmh0511   You're confusing what the standard requires and what implementations can do.  There are plenty of cases implementations elect to reliably produce particular behaviours, where the behaviour is still undefined by the standard (i.e. no implementation provides a yardstick on whether something is undefined by the standard).  On round-trip behaviour, the standard provides relevant guarantees with some integral types (e.g. `std::ptrdiff_t` and `std::size_t`) but those types are, themselves, implementation-defined.   There is certainly no such guarantee for other integral types, like `int`.

Comment: @Peter I don't think you're saying the same things about "UB" the same as mine. I'm asking whether the case is definitely "UB". Implementation-defined behavior is irrelevant to "undefined behavior", they're not the same things. You should point out whether `#2` is UB or implementation-defined behavior. If it is definitely UB, please cite the relevant quote here. I will appreciate it.

Comment: @xmh0511   I said straight-out in the first sentence of my first comment comment that it is undefined behaviour.   You're the one who's arguing it is "not definitely" undefined behaviour because of the interaction with a case of implementation-defined behaviour.      From a standard perspective, if there is any logic path that introduces undefined behaviour into a program, then the behaviour is undefined.    Undefined behaviour means the standard does not constrain what happens, even if there is no quote to be found stating "XXX is undefined".

Comment: @Peter  "UB" is either the standard says "X is undefined behavior" or the standard didn't give the explicit defined behavior. The case is special on that the conversion is implementation defined. I just think we cannot arbitrary consider a implementation defined behavior as UB even if using the result may cause UB. Please see Nicol Bolas's answers.

Comment: @xmh0511   As soon as your argument cites "how the implementation processes the case" you were making an argument about behaviour of your particular (hypothetical?) implementation, not about whether the standard specifies relevant constraints.   The definition of undefined in the standard is that the *standard* doesn't describe any constraints.    You're using a false premise of "if by some implementation-defined logic the implementation doesn't do something with undefined behaviour, then the behaviour is not undefined according to the standard."

Comment: @Peter The standard didn't say there is no requirement in this case. The only requirement is left for implementations, which is implementation-defined. We cannot assume the conversion result points to an actual `int` object or not, hence we cannot straightly say it's UB or not. After all, it's implementation-defined. BTW, suppose that we have a special platform, we do know a physical address can store or read an `int` value, it seems to make no sense if the standard arbitrarily says such use is UB.

Comment: @xmh0511  Again, you resort to an argument about what a hypothetical platform might do so your claim does not hold water.     Undefined behaviour is defined *purely* from the perspective of the *standard*, not in reference to any implementation.   Faced with undefined behaviour an implementation is free to do what it likes - including something that makes sense on a particular target platform, but not with any other implementation.  That choice, by an implementation, has no bearing on whether that behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @Peter How do you think which provision in the standard says it has no requirements in either `#1` or `#2`? The standard explicitly says the result of `#1` is **implementation-defined**, the result of `#2` depends on the result of `#1`(i.e. the value of `ptr`), this chain makes `#2` to be also implementation-defined. This is reasonable.

Comment: @xmh0511   Because it is undefined whether the "special integral value", when converted to a pointer, produces a pointer that validly points to an `int`.   Undefined trumps implementation-defined, not the reverse.

Comment: @Peter You seem to interpret the meaning of "undefined" wider than it should have in the standard. As you said, "Undefined" is a superset of "implementation-defined",  you shouldn't assume the value for `ptr` for which implementations can decide the value.  If you're sure that the value will cause **UB**, that means, you have decided the value for implementation, it does not make sense.

Comment: @xmh0511  I never suggested that undefined behaviour is a superset of implementation-defined behaviour - and you're incorrect in interpreting it that way.  Undefined behaviour means that the standard does not constrain the set of possible behaviours or outcomes in any way.  The standard does not describe any constraints on what happens when any integral value is converted to a pointer and the resultant pointer is dereferenced - so, by definition, the behaviour of your code is undefined.

Comment: @Peter No, the standard does have constraints on "dereference": *《The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points.》*, which means if the pointer value does not point to an object or function, the behavior is undefined. This conclusion depends on what the result of the conversion is. The conversion is implementation-defined, which didn't mean the standard does not have a constraint on it.

Comment: @xmh0511   Name one integral value that, when converted to a pointer, is required by the standard to point at a particular object or function.

Comment: @Peter So why do you think the result of that conversion(implementation-defined) is absolutely not a valid pointer that points to an `int` object? About the difference between implementation-defined and UB, I think http://c-faq.com/ansi/undef.html is a wonderful answer. *implementation-defined: The implementation must pick some behavior; it may not fail to compile the program. (The program using the construct is not incorrect.) The choice must be documented. The Standard may specify a set of allowable behaviors from which to choose, **or it may impose no particular requirements**.*

Comment: @Peter Incidentally, this is the portion of codes that read some information on the platform `STM32`: `chipid.id[0] = *( I uint32 t *) (MCU + 0x00) ；`, where `MCU + 0x00` is a special address represented by integer value. Do you think it's UB? Of course, it's not UB, it's a legal operation on a particular platform, which is permitted by the standard since it's implementation-defined.

Comment: @xmh0511   I don't.  I'm saying that the standard doesn't describe any constraints that require it to point at a valid object.   And you've ignored my last comment.   Name one integral value that the standard requires, if it is converted to a pointer, will point at a valid object.   Come on.   I'm saying the standard describes no constraints, so there is no such value.  All you need to do is provide one counter-example - an integral value that, when converted to a pointer, the standard requires will be a pointer to valid object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard has nothing more to say on it than what you quoted. The standard only guarantees the meaning of a integer-to-pointer cast if that integer value was taken from a pointer-to-integer cast. The meaning of all other integer-to-pointer conversions are implementation defined.

And that means *everything* about them is "implementation defined": what they result in and what using those results will do. After all, the pointer-to-integer-to-pointer round trip spells out that you get the "original value" back. The fact that the resulting pointer has the "original value" means that it will behave exactly like you had copied the original pointer itself. So the standard needs say nothing more on the matter.

The behavior of the pointer taken from an implementation-defined integer-to-pointer cast is... implementation-defined. If an implementation says that supports such conversions, it must spell out what the result of supported conversions are. That is, if there is some "a special integer value" for which a cast to an `int*` is supported by the implementation, it must say what the result of that cast is. This includes things like whether it pointer to an actual `int` or whatever.

Comment: So, you agree the case is **not** definite UB? It may or may not UB, depending on how the implementation processes the case? As the analysis I did.

Answer (score 0):

> Is performing indirection from a pointer acquired from converting an integer value definitely UB?

Not always. Here is an example that is definitely not UB:

```
int i = 42;
std::intptr_t value = reinterpret_cast<std::intptr_t>(&i); 
int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(value);
int v = *ptr;
```

This is because converting a pointer to an integer of sufficient size and back to the same pointer type is guaranteed to yield the same pointer value as stated in the rule you quoted. Since the original pointer value was valid for indirection, so is the converted one.